# Internet Explorer developer tools: Can't find Javascript function definition

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer, developer-tools

I'm trying to track down the code for a button that runs a very generic Javascript function in an object but I'm unable to easily find its definition. I have to use Internet Explorer, and if I do a search in developer tools, it shows all instances of that function call (there're dozens) but not the definition.

There're tens of thousands of lines of Javascript code and I'm having a hard time finding it in developer tools as well as my code editor (there's thousands of files and hundreds of search results for it).

I'm used to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicking a function call in my editor to go to its definition, but this doesn't work in IE dev tools. Is there some easier way to find the function definition than what I'm doing?

Comment: In the code, write `debugger` inside of the function.  When it executes (with the developer tools open) it will break on that line

Comment: @DaveHeq Did you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: I would write debugger inside of the function but I don't know where it's defined; the question was how to easily find it in IE dev tools. My only solution is to scour the source code, and JS functions can be defined several different ways that may not be easy to search for.